# kiln client / only use a ledger with the 8,25% bound on it

Tags: node, kiln

I got a quick question. How do I / can I setup the kiln node with a ledger that has only the 8,25% bound amount of xtz on it? I want to setup the node and let others delegate their stake to my node until i reach the amount of 1 roll.

Am I able to do that (,yet)?

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can currently do this The 'Start Baking' flow will work just fine. Just know that, whether you are using Kiln or not, if you register as a delegate without a roll (currently 8,000 XTZ) you will not receive any rights. If that's the case, Kiln will allow you to register but notify that you have insufficient funds to receive rights.

Regarding the 8.25% - that's the recommended minimum to hold in the baking address, but you can certainly have more than that.

https://medium.com/@obsidian.systems/how-to-install-kiln-and-bake-on-ubuntu-a13d17df63c

Comment: okay thank you for the answer, so I am able to "register" and delegate the other part needed for the roll afterwards, right?

Comment: Correct - You can register with a balance less than a roll, then have funds added or delegated shortly after. Just know that you need to get more than one roll within 5 cycles or else you will go inactive and will need to re-register. Kiln handles this nicely, though - it tells you when you have insufficient funds for rights and when your baker is inactive and must be re-registered.

Comment: tried it , saw it, am impressed. Kiln is really user friendly! Ty for your time

Comment: Fantastic, glad to hear it! It sounds as though this has been solved. If so, can you please mark it as answered? Thanks :)